# Can I receive all the messages I missed whilst my iMessage was off?

Tags: ios, messages

I shut my iMessage off last night on my iPhone 5s. I turned it back on this morning. How can I get the messages I didn't receive?

Comment: How many devices do you have with messages turned on? The answer hinges upon that detail.